# My tkinter image show up as a black screen

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I am trying to code a game for my school assignment. In this game, I wanted to have a mute button so I have made a button on top of a label frame and place it in a label. I don't know what is wrong with it but the image does not show up. I have tried to create a local copy by assigning it to a temp variable and yet it still doesn't show up. Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()

topFrame =Frame(root, width=500, height=50,)
topFrame.grid(row=0, column= 0)

btnframe = LabelFrame(topFrame, width = 20, height = 20)
btnframe.place(x = 450, y= 5 )

mute_image = Image.open("pygame/mute.png")
mute_image = mute_image.resize((50,50), Image.ANTIALIAS)
mute_icon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(mute_image)

mute_button = Button( btnframe, width = 50, height = 50, command = Mute, image = mute_icon)
mute_button.image = mute_icon
mute_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Please go easy on me, this is my first time coding a game ever:)) Thanks in advance:))

Comment: try adding this before mute_image and it might work `global mute_image` and `global mute_icon` i actually tried running this code and it worked for me without any issue tho

Comment: @CoolCloud ***without any issue***: Using `global ...` at `global`scope is useless.

Comment: Can't reproduce your behavior, works for me see [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/BitterEarnestWheel). Verify your image!

Comment: yes it does work for me too, idk wts the real issue here is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you getting any error messages. I slightly modified your code and it complained abuot the button callback function was not defined. After I added that it all seems to work.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()

topFrame =Frame(root, width=500, height=50,)
topFrame.grid(row=0, column= 0)

btnframe = LabelFrame(topFrame, width = 20, height = 20)
btnframe.place(x = 450, y= 5 )

def Mute():
    pass

mute_image = Image.open("images/beer.png")  
mute_image = mute_image.resize((50,50), Image.ANTIALIAS)
mute_icon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(mute_image)

mute_button = Button(btnframe, width=50, height=50,
                     command=Mute, image=mute_icon)
mute_button.image = mute_icon
mute_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```